# Make A Div Resizeable Again After Appending HTML in its InnerHTML

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, resize, autoresize

I have a simple `div` that I made resizable through using [Jquery UI](https://jqueryui.com/resizable/).

```
<div id="myid_templates_editor_text_1"></div>
```

Jquery Code:

```
$('#myid_templates_editor_text_1').resizable({
        animate: true,              
});
```

After doing so, it works fine. See image below:

[image]

[image]

The div can be resize. The code structure of the div turns into the code below after making it resizable using Jquery.

```
<div id="myid_templates_editor_text_1" class="ui-resizable ui-draggable" style="width: 109px; height: 114px; position: absolute; left: 621px; top: 527px;">

    <div class="ui-resizable-handle ui-resizable-e" style="z-index: 90;"></div>
    <div class="ui-resizable-handle ui-resizable-s" style="z-index: 90;"></div>
    <div class="ui-resizable-handle ui-resizable-se ui-icon ui-icon-gripsmall-diagonal-se" style="z-index: 90;"></div>

</div>
```

I want to put a text inside the  resizable div, so I decided to put text inside it by appending an HTML to it's innerHTML. See code below:

```
 var parent = document.getElementById('myid_templates_editor_text_1');      
 parent.innerHTML +=  '<p>Sample Text</p>';
```

After successfully appending, the div's resize functionality is lost? Why? What shall I do to make it working?

Comment: Try to provide fiddle if you have used any library or widget in your example..

Comment: Have you tried [`destroying`](http://api.jqueryui.com/resizable/#method-destroy) and re-initializing Resizable Widget again ?

Comment: Working for me http://jsfiddle.net/Ka7P2/817/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Functionality is lost because you are replacing the current dom elements with new ones that have the same html code. Your code is essentially doing this.

```
parent.innerHTML = parent.innerHTML + '<p>Sample Text</p>';
```

By doing this, the browser is wiping out all of the dom elements that used to exist in `parent` and parses the new html and creates all new dom elements. These new elements don't have the listeners for resizing on them that the old ones did.

A good workaround for this is to just use a child div element and change the inner html of that. For the more advanced route you can modify the div through dom manipulation. You can also call `resizeable` after you set the innerHTML.

Don't call `resizable` multiple times though because you'll start creating many instances of objects that have event listeners bound to many dom elements. You'll create a memory leak.

Answer (score 0):

Why the resizable functionality is lost is because of this line:

```
parent.innerHTML +=  '<p>Sample Text</p>';
```

This re-writes the HTML within the `parent` node, and destroying all existing elements, and all event handlers bound to those elements.

You could instead use

```
var newParagraph = document.createElement('p');

newParagraph.textContent = 'hello';
parent.appendChild(newParagraph);
```

You could also simply re-bind the resizable plugin after updating the HTML:

```
parent.innerHTML +=  '<p>Sample Text</p>';
$('#myid_templates_editor_text_1').resizable({
    animate: true,              
});
```

Answer (score 0):

use innerHTML will overide all sub nodes.
you can put the text in a child node or use appendChild or insertBefore.

HTML code:

```
<div id="myid_templates_editor_text_1" class="ui-resizable ui-draggable" style="width: 109px; height: 114px; position: absolute; left: 621px; top: 527px;">
    <div id="text"></div>
    <div class="ui-resizable-handle ui-resizable-e" style="z-index: 90;"></div>
    <div class="ui-resizable-handle ui-resizable-s" style="z-index: 90;"></div>
    <div class="ui-resizable-handle ui-resizable-se ui-icon ui-icon-gripsmall-diagonal-se" style="z-index: 90;"></div>
</div>
```

JS code:

```
//#text is a child node
$('#text').text('some text');
//or use append
$('#myid_templates_editor_text_1').append('some text');
```